# Runtime Error in titanium app: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, titanium

When I run the code and then fetch the data from the database this error comes.

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb  failed. # Open Cursors=741 (# cursors opened by this proc=741) run time error in titanium app
```

It's basically a database error but I have no solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't close cursor.

You can follow this:

```
 Cursor cursor = null;
  try {
      cursor = query();
  } catch (Exception e) {

  } finally {
      if (cursor != null)
         cursor.close();
   }
```